# Screaming sounds on my front wheel

Tags: mountain-bike, hydraulic-disc-brake

Recently I bought a mountain bike with hydraulic disk brakes.

But when I ride it the front wheel makes screaming sounds, possibly from the disk brake.

I contacted my local dealer and they helped me adjusting the brakes, and I even learn how to do it also.

But it seems the problem happens more than once, every time after I put back the front wheel and start riding. The problem is frustrating; I need about 5 minutes to adjust the brake and tyres every time.

What can I do, should I replace anything?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Padang. I have edited your post to try to make it clearer. If I have changed your intended meaning then please feel free to revert the edit, or edit again

Comment: Disk brakes do that.  (So do rim brakes, but not as often or obnoxiously.)

Comment: Thanks andy, sorry for my English. my old bicycle never have this disk brakes problem before. Local dealer said its one time problem, but its happen twice already. Are this becouse the diak brake are new?

Comment: You might want to see [this question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/28827/what-are-the-negative-consequences-of-not-bedding-in-disc-brakes), and more generally to read up on the "bedding in" process, To an extent, this is perfectly normal (and temporary)

Comment: I had read the bedding in issue, my problem is the brakes doesn't make squealing sound and its work fine. The sound coming from the rotate disk brake touching the brakes pad when my front wheel rotating (without using any brakes) . Is this somehow still relate to the 'bedding in'. If so then i might have to wait n see.

Comment: Finally after some reading, the problem i having e is call brakes rubbing, oh hell, take a while to reach that conclusion. Already understand how to repair it, but any suggestions on how to prevent the problem in future?